# How do I build a 32-bit Debian binary on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, packaging

I would like to build a 32-bit binary for the Atom text editor on 64-bit Ubuntu by building Atom (with `script/build`) and then running `script/grunt mkdeb`). `script/grunt mkdeb` calls on this script to build the Debian binary:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mkdeb name version channel arch control-file-path desktop-file-path icon-path deb-file-path

set -e

SCRIPT=`readlink -f "$0"`
ROOT=`readlink -f $(dirname $SCRIPT)/..`
cd $ROOT

NAME="$1"
VERSION="$2"
CHANNEL="$3"
ARCH="$4"
CONTROL_FILE="$5"
DESKTOP_FILE="$6"
ICON_FILE="$7"
DEB_PATH="$8"
FILE_MODE=755

TARGET_ROOT="`mktemp -d`"
chmod $FILE_MODE "$TARGET_ROOT"
TARGET="$TARGET_ROOT/$NAME-$VERSION-$ARCH"

mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/usr"
env INSTALL_PREFIX="$TARGET/usr" script/grunt install --channel $CHANNEL

mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/DEBIAN"
cp "$CONTROL_FILE" "$TARGET/DEBIAN/control"

mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/usr/share/applications"
cp "$DESKTOP_FILE" "$TARGET/usr/share/applications"

mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/usr/share/pixmaps"
cp "$ICON_FILE" "$TARGET/usr/share/pixmaps/$NAME.png"

# Copy generated LICENSE.md to /usr/share/doc/atom/copyright
mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/usr/share/doc/$NAME"
cp "$TARGET/usr/share/$NAME/resources/LICENSE.md" "$TARGET/usr/share/doc/$NAME/copyright"

# Add lintian overrides
mkdir -m $FILE_MODE -p "$TARGET/usr/share/lintian/overrides"
cp "$ROOT/resources/linux/debian/lintian-overrides" "$TARGET/usr/share/lintian/overrides/$NAME"

# Remove executable bit from .node files
find "$TARGET" -type f -name "*.node" -exec chmod a-x {} \;

fakeroot dpkg-deb -b "$TARGET"
mv "$TARGET_ROOT/$NAME-$VERSION-$ARCH.deb" "$DEB_PATH"
rm -rf "$TARGET_ROOT"
```

the most important line of this file is the `dpkg-deb` line, I believe, is there some option I can pass to dpkg-deb to get it to build for the 32-bit architecture despite running on a 64-bit instance of Ubuntu 16.04? If you are wondering why I don't use the Atom PPA instead for 32-bit systems, it's because I am building a custom version of Atom, with a few Atom packages removed and few others added.